# Create Facebook App from PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook

I know this has been asked before, but how can I create a Facebook App programmatically?

Everyone awnsers that its not possible, but there are multiple applications (Wildfire, Shortstack, etc...) that create a Facebook Apps and deploy to a Page Tab automatically.

How can they create the facebook Apps?

Comment: They don't. They just install 1 app to a number of pages and use the signed_request to work out what page it is on and what data to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab apps can be installed on multiple pages - they are sill all the same application with the same APP_ID (you can check this yourself).

I think you are confusing the procedure of adding a new tab application to a page with creating a new application.

**Adding an application to a page does not create a new instance of the application.**

To directly answer your question: You can not programaticaly create Facebook applications.

Comment: My problem isn't installing the same app on diferent page tabs, I know you can do that.
I'm developing a software that should create facebook apps and deploy them to the client Facebook Page. I just don't know how to create the Facebook Apps programmatically, just like Wildfire and Shortstack does... They create multiple apps that get deployed to the user Facebook Page

Comment: I'm not familiar with the examples you've given. But I do know that **no one** can dynamically create applications. They are obviously using some pre-made application and only adding some customization..

Comment: Pre-made apps, thats what I thought. But I'm having trouble imagining that Wildfire with their hundreds of users having to pre-create each Facebook App manually.

Comment: What I mean is that all users are essentially getting the same pre-made app. Think about it this way - changing only a css file can give an application a totally different look even though the underlying markup hasn't changed at all...

Comment: But since one App has only one Canvas URL, how can they differentiate each "application"?

Comment: Aha! THAT is the trick ;) [TommyBs left a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704658/create-facebook-app-from-php-sdk/17704722?noredirect=1#comment25800242_17704658) on your question with the answer to that. You can extract that info from the `signed_request`.

Comment: GREAT! Actualy your comment got me thinking on how to differentiate the request in the app and I got to the same conclusion after some Googling. Thank you